# How to dynamically update NavBar variables using onMouseDown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this navigation bar (NavBar) and it's basically a list of dictionaries:

```
render() {
    let links = [
      { label: "Your Videos", link: "/landingpage/videos", active: true },
      { label: "Stats", link: "/landingpage/stats", active: false },
      { label: "Process", link: "/landingpage/process", active: false },
      { label: "Contact", link: "/landingpage/contact", active: false }
    ];
    let linksMarkup = links.map((link, index) => {
      let linkMarkup = link.active ? (
        <a className="menu__link menu__link--active" href={link.link}>
          {link.label}
        </a>
      ) : (
        <a className="menu__link" href={link.link}>
          {link.label}
        </a>
      );
      return (
        <li key={index} className="menu__list-item">
          {linkMarkup}
        </li>
      );
    });
    return (
      <nav className="menu">
        <a href="/landingpage/videos">
          <div
            style={{
              backgroundImage: "url(" + logo + ")"
            }}
            className="menu__logo"
          />
        </a>
        <div className="menu__right">
          <ul className="menu__list">{linksMarkup}</ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
```

The `active` determines which menu item has this awesome orange styling on it. My problem is that no matter what you click, the default landing page, `Your Videos` is always styled with orange.

I want to find a way so that when users click on a menu item, it will change to have orange styling (`active: true`) and the rest will be `active: false`.

I've tried to do this using Javascript function, but to be honest I'm not sure where to start besides that.

Edit: 
My Header.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Header.css";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from "../photos/logo_small.png";

class Header extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showForm: false,
      activeItem: null
    };
  }

  showForm() {
    this.setState({
      showForm: !this.state.showForm
    });
  }

  // Changes which menu item has orange bar on it
  onChangeHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ activeItem: navItem1 });
  };

  render() {
    let links = [
      { label: "Your Videos", link: "/landingpage/videos" },
      { label: "Stats", link: "/landingpage/stats" },
      { label: "Process", link: "/landingpage/process" },
      { label: "Contact", link: "/landingpage/contact" }
    ];
    let linksMarkup = links.map((link, index) => {
      let linkMarkup = link.active ? (
        <a className="menu__link menu__link--active" href={link.link}>
          {link.label}
        </a>
      ) : (
        <a className="menu__link" href={link.link}>
          {link.label}
        </a>
      );
      return (
        <li
          key={index}
          className="menu__list-item"
          onChange={this.onChangeHandler(thisNavItem)}
          className={this.state.activeItem === navItem1 ? blue : orange}
        >
          {linkMarkup}
        </li>
      );
    });
    return (
      <nav className="menu">
        <a href="/landingpage/videos">
          <div
            style={{
              backgroundImage: "url(" + logo + ")"
            }}
            className="menu__logo"
          />
        </a>
        <div className="menu__right">
          <ul className="menu__list">{linksMarkup}</ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Header);
```

My Header.css:

```
/* MENU STYLING */
.blue {
  color: orange;
}

.white {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Seems you are missing some basic React's concepts like "state". Your `links` array is a static local variable, it will never change.

I suggest you to read some tutorials, the risk is to waste lot of time on basic concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can use ReactJs state in order to accomplish your task.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Active makes no sense in my opinion. Just differentiate via class. Define two classes like so:

```
.blue {
    color: blue;
}

.orange {
    color: orange;
}
```

Your state could look like so:

```
state: {
   activeItem: null;
}
```

then use something like this for your onChange event and the handler:

```
onChange={this.onChangeHandler(thisNavItem)}

onChangeHandler = () => (this.setState({
        activeItem: navItem1;
    ))
```

then just add classes based on state like so:

```
className={{this.state.activeItem === navItem1 ? blue : orange }}
```

Comment: What is ```onChangeHandler```? Doesn't look like a function. Also I took this NavBar code online somewhere so I was just trying to roll with what they had, I didn't see anything wrong with it. Also, your code doesn't make sense. You never call onChangeHandler() anywhere.

Comment: Where does ```onChange={this.onChangeHandler(thisNavItem)}``` go?

Comment: This should go onto each nav bar item. So that it catches each onChange event. So that onChangeHandler is triggered on each click.

Comment: I'm going to edit my post. I'm doing what you're saying but it's not working. I'm getting a lot of ```'' is not defined``` errors.

Comment: Hmm i dont have the time atm to write a full prototype sadly. Start with reading [my link](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 0):

Put links into state, update their active attribute in onClick.

Comment: If you tried it, then that's the code you should have posted here. What you posted suggests you don't understand basic concepts of react/js scopes.

Comment: Yeah, it failed totally and I didn't want to confuse people with my failed solution. I wanted to see what other code people would come with.